# mysql find out ids which are not present in 2 columns of a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of entries A.

In table B, I have two columns with ids of entries in A (lets call them col1 and col2). How do I get the list of IDs in A which are not in both of these columns of B.

The query i used was

```
select A.id from A where A.id not in (select distinct B.col1 from B) and A.id not in   (select distinct B.col2 from B);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID
FROM    A
WHERE   ID NOT IN
    (SELECT colA as ID From B 
         Union 
     Select colB as ID From B)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want those that are "not in both of these columns of B", you want those that are either not in col1 or not in col2 or in none of them, so you have to change your AND to OR:

```
select A.id from A  
  where A.id not in (select distinct B.col1 from B) 
  or A.id not in   (select distinct B.col2 from B);
```